# Hotel reservation plugin you would recommend

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

What hotel reservation plugins for Wordpress would you recommend for a Small hotel that has not more than 25 rooms? It needs to display room availability and can accept payment online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/booking/ There is a free version and a few very nicely featured paid upgrade services depending on your needs on their website.